# Laravel-like routing pattern in Flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, react-router, parameter-passing

I'm looking for a routing in Flutter similar to Laravel/Lumen that follows this pattern:

```
project/{project}
```

where {project} is required id. Explicitly specifying the id is important because the app is heavilly used on the web and users bookmarking their projects and organizations is a known necessity.

What I have tried so far:

```
initialRoute: '/',
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
   // '/': (context) => Dashboard(), // error LOL
   '/login': (context) => Login(),
   '/projects': (context) => Projects(),
   '/project/{id}': (context) => Dashboard(), // <-- just an example of what I want. obviously not working
},
```

While the `login` and `projects` routes work, the `project/{id}` route does not.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: is this what you want https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments?

Comment: I've already tried that approach but it seems it does not support explicitly specifying the argument on the route pattern.

Comment: check out https://pub.dev/packages/fluro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter's routing is a total mess. While its default routing is OK on mobile and desktop applications, the need for web apps to have dynamic routing support like Laravel and Angular, something that have explicit parametert embedding in the URL and ones that you actually bookmark is far fom acceptable. At the time of writing, it's web support is still in beta.

One solution that I found is [fluro](https://pub.dev/packages/fluro)

Add to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  fluro:
    git: git://github.com/theyakka/fluro.git
```

Create app-router.dart

```
import 'package:fluro/fluro.dart';
import 'package:proj/pages/mypage.dart';
import 'package:proj/pages/anotherpage.dart';

class AppRouter {
  static final AppRouter _instance = new AppRouter._internal();
  final Router _router = new Router();

  factory AppRouter(context) {
    return _instance;
  }

  AppRouter._internal();

  // singleton
  Router router() {
    return _router;
  }

  void configureRoutes() {
    _router.define("/user/:id",
        handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
          return MyPage(id: params['id'][0].toString());
    }));

    _router.define("/another-route/:id",
        handler: Handler(handlerFunc: (context, Map<String, dynamic> params) {
          return AnotherPage(id: params['id'][0].toString());
    }));
  }
}
```

To use:

```
new AppRouter(context).router().navigateTo(context,                                      "/user/" + org['id'].toString());
```

Done!

Answer (score 0):

As much as understand your idea, it's always better to pass the data via the widget constructors.

```
class DashBoard extends StatefulWidget {
  final int id;

  const DashBoard({Key key, this.id}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DashBoardState createState() => _DashBoardState();
}

class _DashBoardState extends State<DashBoard> {
  void initState() {
    // you can use the id here
    print(widget.id);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Then you can Navigate as:

```
Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => DashBoard(
                id: 1,
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Hope this will help

Comment: How does this apply to routes like "project/1"?

Comment: Read some information from [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) . Though I don't prefer using this method.

Comment: Routes like "project/1" are named routes, they take an optional `arguments` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternatively, you can do as below

Define the arguments you need to pass.

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  ScreenArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

Create a widget that extracts the arguments

```
// A widget that extracts the necessary arguments from the ModalRoute.
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/extractArguments';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute settings and cast
    // them as ScreenArguments.
    final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.message),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Register the widget in the routes table

```
MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName: (context) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
  },
);
```

Navigate to the widget

```
// A button that navigates to a named route. The named route
// extracts the arguments by itself.
RaisedButton(
  child: Text("Navigate to screen that extracts arguments"),
  onPressed: () {
    // When the user taps the button, navigate to a named route
    // and provide the arguments as an optional parameter.
    Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
      arguments: ScreenArguments(
        'Extract Arguments Screen',
        'This message is extracted in the build method.',
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Success